# Getting name of the next-to root node and the concatenation of path to it

Tags: xslt, elasticsearch, xpath, xquery, xpath-2.0

I am parsing ElasticSearch metadata and trying to access two values.
Given this XML:

```
<root>
    <index1>
        <mappings>
            <users>
                <properties>
                    <birthDate>
                        <type>date</type>
                    </birthDate>
                    <born>
                        <properties>
                            <city>
                                <type>text</type>
                            </city>
                        </properties>
                    </born>
                </properties>
            </users>
        </mappings>
    </index1>
</root>
```

1. Listing all names of children of properties that are basic objects (without children of name "properties") is straightforward:

   ```
   //properties/*[not(properties)]/name()
   ```

this returns "birthDate", "city"

2. I try to get the top node before the root from the anchor node from section 1 above, in this case, crom "birthplace" and "city" I try to reach "index1". What I reached is

   ```
   ancestor::*[ancestor::root]/name()
   ```

which is still not correct

3. I need to concatenate the path from the anchor node to the index node, separating with underscores. So, most likely this is `string-join` of the `//ancestor` with a certain condition.

Could you please advise on 2) and 3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2. Select the second to last ancestor node: `$anchor//ancestor::*[last() - 1]`
3. Select all ancestors until the second to last, reverse, and string join their names: `string-join(reverse($anchor//ancestor::*[position() le last() - 1]/name()), '_')`

Comment: Could you please tell how this syntax is referenced in the docs:
[1 to last() - 1], because this is the only part which I cannot let work, but probably I'm somewhere wrong with the anchor node.

Comment: @EugeneBykov Sorry, that was an implementation-specific syntax I used out of habit. I updated the answer to use the W3C syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the code, works as a charm! "le" means "less or equals", right? Is there a way to have several conditions in these brackets (that is "more than" and "excluding nodes with the name "properties")?

Comment: @EugeneBykov Yes, and you can use Boolean logic and grouping  (see the spec) within the predicate to compose more complex conditions.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: Finally ended up with
`string-join(reverse(.//ancestor::*[position() le last() - 5 and position() > 1][name(parent::*)="properties"]/name()), ''_'')`, which returns "birthDate" and "city_born", that were my ultimate goal